# How to prevent UILabel from being moved further than other objects

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to move a label with an animation but I want it to be between two other objects. I thought I could do it with NSLayoutConstraints like

```
    let labelLeftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.leftObject, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let labelRightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.LessThanOrEqual, toItem: self.rightObject, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let labelBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.bottomObject , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let labelCenterX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.movingObject, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(label)
    self.view.addConstraints([labelLeftConstraint, labelRightConstraint, labelBottom, labelCenterX])
```

And I am trying to update the position with

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.movingObject.center = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
        self.view.updateConstraints()
    }
```

But when the `movingObject` is moving too far it crops the label (which obviously makes sense because of the `labelCenterX` should be equal to the `movingObject`). How could I prevent this and instead move it only up to the edges of the `leftObject` and `rightObject`? I would need something like `.LessEqualOrGreater` as for the relation...

I also tried to animate the label also with the `.center`-method but I didn't find a way to prevent it from getting out of the two objects.

Thank You for your Help (I know I am probably asking a dumb question but I am just learning Swift)

**Edit:**
Here is a Screenshot of my problem:
[image: The thing I try to animate]

The movingObject is the picture of bike which moves with changing velocity from left to right and is allowed to go further than the label with the velocity over the bar. This label should only be between the `0` and the `30`-Label

**Edit 2:**
The working code is in my [Git repository](https://github.com/miallo/Problem)

Comment: Can you try animating the `movingObject`'s constraint instead of center? That might help make everything animatable ... Also, can you extract the code out to a working project and post a link to GitHub?

Comment: I will trie but the whole project got a complicated...

Comment: I hope it will work for you: https://github.com/miallo/Problem.git

Comment: @Jure I added a function that switches between the two methods I tried so you can see both working.

Comment: Try setting `speedCenterX.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow;`. The default priority for constraints is `UILayoutPriorityRequired`, so there is probably a layout ambiguity (check your console if any).

Comment: @Sega-Zero This sounds really promising but I get the error `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow", referenced from:
      __TFC8AmpelApp15ViewController210initLayoutfS0_FT_T_ in ViewController2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Your solution almost works. I had to change it to `speedCenterX.priority = 10 as UILayoutPriority`because of an error. If you ad this as an answer I will accept this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to create required leading/trailing constraints >= 0 and a centerX constraint with a lower priority, then changing a centerX constant to whatever you need.